# Empty Node.js/Express response

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have a POST request that I want to process:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser());
. . .
app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    console.log('name: ' + req.body.name);
    console.log('email: ' + req.body.email);
    . . .
});
```

All seems well and dandy.

My client:

```
<html><body>
    <form>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('input#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/signup',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('response:', data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script></body></html>
```

The problem? `success` is never called in the client. Eventually, Chrome JS-debug window shows: `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

I have tried doing `res.send(200)`, `res.send('')` and `res.end()` in the server, but without success.

My Node.js version is 4.2.6, and I think my Express version is 4.4.1.

Comment: Could you add **all** of your app's routing function, as it's hard to help when the response part is missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**jQuery Docs**

> dataType - The type of data that you're expecting back from the server;
>
> data - Data to be sent to the server;

So, your frontend application expect a valid JSON back, but primaries (string, number, boolean) aren't a valid JSON, they have to be converted.

In order to perform this on fly:

```
res.json('success');
```

or

```
res.status(200).json('success');
```

If you want to stick with send method, you could write:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify('success'));
```

Also, sometimes this problem is related to ipconfig in windows and network connection

Comment: My frontend expects json because I could not understand from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) what to do for empty responses. Do you know if it is possible to accept an empty response? I would prefer that it just waits for status 200, and then goes to success. Is that possible?

Comment: Changing client to expect `text/html`, and then server to `res.status(200)` or `res.send('')` does not work. But `json` with `res.json('success')` does work, which is good enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this,

```
$.post('http://localhost:5000/signup', $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```